# A room list of each apartment foreign key link

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I want to display a list of the room that belongs to each apartment, the condition is that each apartment has a number of rooms and logically each room belongs to one apartment, models is as follows :

**models.py**

```
  class apartement(models.Model):
            user = models.OneToOneField(User,related_name='user')
            name = models.CharField(default=0)
            def __unicode__(self):
                    return u'%s' % self.user

    class room(models.Model):
            apartement = models.ForeignKey(apartement)
            type = models.CharField(max_length=256)
            capacity = models.IntegerField()
            def __unicode__(self):
                    return u'%s' % (self.type)
```

**view.py**

```
apartement1 = apartement.objects.filter(user=request.user)
room1 = room.objects.select_related()
response['room1']=room1
```

**template.py**

```
{% for r in room1 %}
                        <td>{{ r.type }}</td>
                        <td> {{r.capacity}}</td>

    {% endfor %}
```

It's not display what I want, I think  problem in the code itself, could someone help me.?

Comment: You haven't told us what you want or how that is different from what you're seeing.

Comment: the answer is in the title, I want to display a room list for each apartment and there's a one-to-many relationship with apartement and room

Comment: with what I've done, I get all the same rooms than other apartments

Comment: But your models have no relationship between apartment and room.

Comment: yes, you're right, it is a mistake to copy and paste, I'll edit it

Answer (score 1):

You should add a foreign key to the `apartement` into the `room` model:

```
class room(models.Model):
        apartement = models.ForeignKey(apartement)
        type = models.CharField(max_length=256)
        capacity = models.IntegerField()
        def __unicode__(self):
                return u'%s' % (self.type)
```

And then get a list of rooms:

```
apartements = apartement.objects.get(user=request.user)
rooms = apartements.room_set.all()
```

Template:

```
{% for r in rooms %}
    <td>{{ r.type }}</td>
    <td>{{ r.capacity }}</td>
{% endfor %}
```

**EDIT**: In case if you don't need to get `apartement` instance you can get the same list of rooms with this code:

```
rooms = room.objects.filter(apartement__user=request.user)
```

Comment: Thanks for ur answer, but doing that I have this error 'apartement' object has no attribute 'room_set'

Comment: What is the `compte` object?  And what is the `Transaction_set`? I don't see such names in your code.

Comment: I need to get apartement with this method : apartement1 = apartement.objects.filter(user=request.user)

Comment: I edit-it, it's  'apartement' object has no attribute 'room_set' , refresh the page

Comment: `apartement` object **has** a `room_set` queryset. It is automatically added by `ForeignKey(apartement)` field. Read the documentation here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward

Comment: As for `filter(user=request.user)`: this method returns a queryset, not an object. And this queryset contains maximum one object because there is a OneToOne relation. So the `get()` is the way to get an `apartement` object. And don't forget to except `DoesNotExist` exception.